# issue with fixed left navigation

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I am having a simple layout with a fixed left navigation and a centered page, now the issue in on low resolutions the fixed navigation is comping on the content area which I want to prevent, but I am not able to do so.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hTqPk/)

Any idea how I can keep my page centered and even the fixed with div just adjacent to it without overlapping my elements when screen resolution is low

What I want is like this no matter whatever resolution  it is in, the page should be centered but the navigation should sit right besides the page and shouldn't overlap page

[image]

CSS

```
.page_wrapper {
    min-width: 750px;
    max-width: 750px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.content_wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

p,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#nav {
  left: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
}
#nav li {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#nav a {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav a:hover {
  background: #dedede;
}
#nav .current a {
  background: #666;
  color: #ededed;
}
.current {
  background: red;
}

.section {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
.section p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

​

Comment: see my answer and fiddle and let me know if i am lagging anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an example fiddle for you, what you just need is a wrapper div and a content div which is floated to right

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xU8Ke/1/)

I've changed some of the container div layout and basically you can wrap up the contents in your container

HTML

```
<div class="main_container">
   <nav class="content_navigation">
      <ul id="nav">
          <li class="current"><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#section-5">Section 5</a></li>
       </ul>
   </nav>
   <div class="right_content">
   <div class="section" id="section-1">
      <strong>Section 1</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section-2">
       <strong>Section 2</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section-3">
       <strong>Section 3</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section-4">
       <strong>Section 4</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section-5">
        <strong>Section 5</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.main_container {
    width: 900px;
    min-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ffffff;
}
.content_navigation {
    width: 205px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 120px;
}
.right_content {
    float: right;
    width: 675px;
    border-left: 1px solid #252525;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
#nav {
  list-style: none;
}
#nav li {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#nav a {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav a:hover {
  background: #dedede;
}
#nav .current a {
  background: #666;
  color: #ededed;
}
.current {
  background: red;
}
.section {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
.section p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, your "left" property on #nav is causing it to always position always 300px from the left margin. Removing that keeps the left nav on the left (instead of 300px from the left).

Instead of:

```
#nav {
  left: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
}
```

try

```
#nav {
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
}
```

See [W3 Schools Left Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp) for more info.

In response to your comment "that will make position navigation to flow on the extreme left of the page" :

Add a `margin-left:20px;` property

Comment: that will make position navigation to flow on the extreme left of the page

Comment: i do really very appreciate your work here but please don't suggest w3schools its terrible source

Answer (score 2):

this can be done by

```
#nav {
    padding-left:20px;  
    padding-top:30px;
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
}
```

### [Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xU8Ke/)

Comment: this is a better solution too, didn't understood why downvoted?

Comment: @Mr.Alien might be because some people appreciated answer by down voting ...:) but no problem for me ...

Comment: lol this was better than my answer, didn't had to change the markup

Answer (score 0):

use `left: 50%` with negative `left-margin` to position the `#nav` from the middle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/hTqPk/3/)

```
#nav {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-350px;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is cool but can I've a CSS solution? or you are getting the bounty

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make something resembling what you have in the diagram, making `#nav` absolutely positioned wrt `.left_navigation`. Also removed the margin on `.content_wrapper` since it didn't seem to serve a purpose.

```css
.content_wrapper {
  /*margin-left: 120px;*/
}
#nav {
  left:-77px;
  width:76px;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
}
.left_navigation{
    position:relative;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hTqPk/5/)

Comment: I meant the content+menu should be in center